# re-run a css animation in lightning web components

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, css3

I want to run a css animation on button click. I have an animation that is run when another animation ends after that I want that animation to be run on a button click. Right now I have the animation running the first when the preceding animation ends.

These are the few things are tried:

1. I tried removing the class and re-adding it.// didn't work.
2. I saw somewhere mentioning to set

   `void element offSetWdith = 0;`/ // didn't work.
3. I took the element off the DOM and re-added it by setting

   `<template if:true={condition}>` // didn't work.

Here is the code I have now:

```
 <div class="cities-section">
     <lightning-card>
    //animation played out on the cities-section element
    </lightning-card>
 </div>
CSS
.cities-section {
    margin-left: 10px;
    opacity: 0;
}
.cities-list-animation {
    animation: citiesLoadAnimation 0.4s forwards 0s ease;
}
@keyframes citiesLoadAnimation {
0% {
    opacity: 0;
}

100% {
    opacity: 1;
}
}

JS
  mapAnimationEnds() {
    this.template.querySelector('.cities-section').classList.add('cities-list-animation');
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers calculate a sort of "delta", as does Lightning, so you just need a small render delay to allow the first set of changes to finish rendering before starting more. The following works for me in this [playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/XdWvb5dZT/1/edit):

```
    this.template.querySelector('.cities-section').classList.remove('cities-list-animation');
    setTimeout(() =>
    this.template.querySelector('.cities-section').classList.add('cities-list-animation'));
```

This is basically "option 1" from your answer, but keeping in mind that you need to introduce a render cycle to make this work.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox, the above is working. also thanks to the Playground linked, that helped.